# Open page in new tab without closing menu

Tags: macos, google-chrome, bookmarks

In my bookmarks bar in Chrome I have a folder with bookmarks. If I click the folder I see the links in this folder. I don't want to open all links in this folder, but a few. On Windows I can simply ctrl+click any link in this folder and it will open that page in a new tab without closing the current folder so I can quickly click the next link.
In Chrome on OSX once I click Cmd+link the page is opened in a new tab, but then it closes the Chrome foldermenu...is there a way to prevent that menu from closing?

Answer (score 1):

Although I hesitate to assert that there is no analogous function in Chrome on OS X, I can’t find one built in.  However, there are some plugins that might help, such as the [Mouse Gesture Extension](http://www.chromeplugins.org/extensions/chrome-gestures-google-chrome-mouse-gestures-extension/) and [Shortcut Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shortcut-manager/mgjjeipcdnnjhgodgjpfkffcejoljijf), although you will need to fiddle with these a bit to get the feature you want.  I hope this helps.